# AWS ECS places one task per EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create a deployment where as many tasks as possible are on each EC2 instance, but ECS still places one task per instance which then makes them heavily underutilized.

Here's all the settings I think are relevant:

- ASG capacity provider uses managed scaling, target capacity is set to 100%, instances are t3a.micro (2048 CPU, 960 memory)
- Task uses 480 memory, 1024 CPU but for testing I tried to go to 200 memory and 500 CPU and nothing changed
- The service placement strategies are binpack(cpu) and binpack(memory)
- The tasks are in a public VPC within subnets that have access to nat gateway, public ip assign is disabled, the networking mode is *awsvpc*
- I'm changing the desired count to test this

On every deploy tasks are placed into empty instances and if there aren't any ASG creates new ones, there's never more than one task per instance.

Comment: What is your network configuration?

Comment: @PawelKam What exactly do you mean? The tasks are in a public VPC within subnets that have access to nat gateway, public ip assign is disabled, the networking mode is awsvpc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the micro EC2 instance you require doesn't have enough ENI capacity to scale more than 1 task per container instance.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-networkmode-awsvpc.html):

> With the awsvpc network mode, Amazon ECS creates and manages an
> Elastic Network Interface (ENI) for each task and each task receives
> its own private IP address within the VPC. This ENI is separate from
> the underlying hosts ENI. If an Amazon EC2 instance is running
> multiple tasks, then each task’s ENI is separate as well.

[image: awsvpc mode]

Since "*this ENI is separate from the underlying hosts ENI*", running 1 ECS task requires at least 2 interfaces. In case of running 2 ECS tasks you would need 3 ENI and so on.
When I get a description of EC2 instance types (you can just run `aws ec2 describe-instance-types --filters "Name=instance-type,Values=t3a.micro"`) I see that ***t3a.micro* has a maximum limit of only 2 available network interfaces** ("MaximumNetworkInterfaces": 2). So, you need to make better use of the existing maximum number of network interfaces or to get a container instance with capacity to attach more network interfaces.

A solution might be to use an instance type with more ENI capability or to increase task density with **ENI trunking**. Please read about [ENI trunking considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-instance-eni.html) before. ENI trunking might look something like this:

[image: ENI trunking]

Comment: It was exactly that, thank you! Don't know how I managed to miss it in the documentation.

Comment: Hi, did you managed to do it with a T3 instance or had to use another type?